# VBA code that will Copy and paste values to the correct location in a table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which I enter data into each day. At the end of the week the data is summarized in a table.

When I start the next week I clear all the contents and start again.

I would like to be able to run a macro at the end of the week which copies the summary table and pastes (as values) into a separate worksheet so that I have the historical data record.

The macro would just have to copy a selection, find the appropriate date in a column heading and paste values.

I'm completely new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.  At least post a sample of the data you are trying to process.

Comment: If you are completely new to `VBA` then I will suggest  you to start with [recoding your macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-CD56FB86-D8B2-475C-BA39-9728389FEEEB), do  little research in [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vba]+copy+paste+vba) great examples here also look at [Getting Started with VBA in Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx) then edit your question with what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

actually i figured something out that works: But if anyone has any suggestions for better ways of achieving the same result id like to hear

```
    Sub history()
    'x is set as the date of the current data set. It looks for the same date in a blank table and pastes the values below it

    x = Cells(20, 2)
    Range("B21:O34").Select
    Selection.Copy

    For i = 1 To 1000
    If Cells(3, i) = x Then

    Range((Cells(5, i).Address)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


    Exit For
    Else
    End If
    Next i  

    End Sub
```

Thanks